# Can we cleanup [conform]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, clean-up

[conform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conform) tag has 39 questions and has no tag guidance. I tried to create one assuming it was for elixir conform tool, but as it turns out it was created for Hibernate [ConfORM](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781849513043/1/ch01lvl1sec14/mapping-with-conform) instead. The question is also used with Swift tag for some reason.

Could we clean it up so that the tag is not ambiguous?

Comment: Why not just burniate it? The Elixir and Hibernate tools could have dedicated tags, but 39 questions is a very small number, indeed.

Comment: The swift questions are using the tag because they want their code to *conform* to a specified Protocol (eg an Interface in Java terms). I guess that’s the verb used in the Swift documentation for Protocols.

Comment: Ugh, there are also posts that simply misspelled “confirm”.

Comment: After cleaning out the Swift protocol, confirm dialogs, and compiler errors that use the verb ‘to conform’ posts, there are 3 elixir and 21 nhibernate posts left. All of them several years old. I don’t think we really need this tag. We _maybe_ could create a hybernate-conform tag.